# Rubyracer Gem on Mavericks with Ruby 1.8.7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, osx-mavericks

I've done some extensive googling on this install issue and have tried almost everything that looked like a solution with no joy. For those that have experienced the same issue, can anyone give me any pointers on where to go next with the bundle install error i'm getting please.

My bundle will install without the RubyRacer but as this app is old and runs on Heroku's Bamboo stack I need it there.

The gemfile has `gem 'therubyracer', '0.10.2'`

The bundle install error is:

```
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /Users/ryanberry/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-head/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/ryanberry/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-head/bin/ruby
extconf.rb:13: uninitialized constant Gem (NameError)
Checking for Python...

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/ryanberry/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/gems/libv8-3.3.10.4 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/ryanberry/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/gems/libv8-3.3.10.4/ext/libv8/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing libv8 (3.3.10.4), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install libv8 -v '3.3.10.4'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Thanks in advance, tearing my hair out with this one and getting grief from colleagues who are waiting on new dev work to be pushed.

Comment: Too many things to list, but a few are; installing different versions of gcc, changing the version of rubyracer and more desperately trying to upgrade my app to ruby 1.9.x, trying to move my app to Heroku's Cedar stack neither which are a small task given the size of the app.

Comment: I think `therubyracer` needs only in linux, so if it's possible for you to change Gemfile you can change it to `gem 'therubyracer', '0.10.2', group :linux` and try app works or not after bundle.

Comment: @zishe That looks like a great solution but it still fails unfortunately. Could this be something to with me running Ruby 1.8.7 on this app?

Comment: probably yes, it's really ancient.